# Xamarin Forms Azure error

Tags: xamarin, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-sql

Estoy tratando de conectar una aplicacion de Xamarin Forms con Microsoft Azure y al momento de compilar me despliega el sig error:

```
Method 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression' not found.
```

Azure Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
namespace Catcher
{
    public class AzureClient
    {

        private IMobileServiceClient client;
        private IMobileServiceTable<Registro> table;

        public AzureClient()
        {

            client = new MobileServiceClient("http://catcher.azurewebsites.net");
            table = client.GetTable<Registro>();

        }

        public Task<IEnumerable<Registro>> GetUsers() {

            return table.ToEnumerableAsync();

        }

    }
}
```

Registro.cs

```
    using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Catcher
{
    [DataTable("users")]
    public class Registro
    {

        [JsonProperty("user")]
        public string user { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("password")]
        public string password { get; set; }

    }
}
```

registro_page.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Catcher
{
    public partial class Registro_Page : ContentPage
    {

        private AzureClient client;
        public ObservableCollection<Registro> users { get; set; }
        public Command RefreshCommand { get; set; }

        public Registro_Page()
        {
            users = new ObservableCollection<Registro>();
            RefreshCommand = new Command(() => Load());
            client = new AzureClient();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public async void Load() {

            IsBusy = true;
            users.Clear();

            var result = await client.GetUsers();

            foreach (var user in result) {

                users.Add(user);

            }

            IsBusy = false;

        }

    }
}
```

app.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Catcher
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        private Registro_Page registroPage;

        public App()
        {   
            InitializeComponent();

            registroPage = new Registro_Page();
            MainPage = new Registro_Page();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
            registroPage.Load();
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

El error aparece comúnmente cuando no se ha importado correctamente las librerías NuGet del paquetes Microsoft.Net.HttpClient que es el que se utiliza para las operaciones HTTPS / REST con Xamarin. Este paquete debe ser instalado correctamente tanto en el PCL como en los proyectos específicos de cada plataforma antes de realizar cualquier tipo de conexión HTTP.